# How to fix onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type Fragment error in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to detect if the back button was pressed in one of my Fragments using onKeyDown but I get the error

> The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type Fragment

at the end of the function. Is there a way to use this function in Fragments?

```
public class FragmentStory4 extends Fragment {
    public FragmentStory4 () {

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story4, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and tell me :)

```
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);
        view.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
                    // here your code
              } 
         });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error "The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type Object" when I try returning again

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is working. when using fragment and declare the onCreateView as below.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_layout, container, false);

rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keycode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keycode==keyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                flag=false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```